# Arithmetic Sequences in Finite Set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Consider a finite set $S\subset \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ which contains no arithmetic sequences of length greater than $l$. For each arithmetic sequence of length $l$ contained in $S$, place the greatest element of this arithmetic sequence in a new set, which we call $\overline{S}$. For what values of $l$ is it possible for $$|S\setminus \overline{S}|<|\overline{S}|$$ For $l=3$, the set $A=\{1, 17, 41, 52, 69, 79, 81, 86, 87, 89, 92, 93, 94\}$ (which has no arithmetic sequences of length $4$) has $\overline{A}=\{81, 86, 87, 89, 92, 93, 94\}$, so the inequality can be satisfied. However, it seems like finding such a set should not be possible for $l\geq4$, but I can't find a nice proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a set $S$ with the properties you want for every value of $l$. Here are a few examples for the smaller values of $l$:

- For $l=2$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=1 < |\bar{S}|=2$ 
  $$       S= \{1,2,4\}$$
  $$ \bar{S}= \{2,4\}$$
- For $l=3$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=3  < |\bar{S}|=4$ 
  $$       S= \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9\}$$
  $$ \bar{S}= \{3, 5, 8, 9\}$$
- For $l=4$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=6  < |\bar{S}|=7$ 
  $$       S= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16\}$$
  $$ \bar{S}= \{4, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 16\}$$
- For $l=5$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=16 < |\bar{S}|=17$ 
  $$       S= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47\}$$
  $$ \bar{S}= \{5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47\}$$
- For $l=6$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=15 < |\bar{S}|=16$ 
  $$       S= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36\}$$
  $$ \bar{S}= \{6, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36\}$$
- For $l=7$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=78 < |\bar{S}|=79$ , $\max(S)=239$
- For $l=8$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=109 < |\bar{S}|=110$ , $\max(S)=335$
- For $l=9$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=213 < |\bar{S}|=214$ , $\max(S)=633$
- For $l=10$:  $|S \setminus \bar{S}|=45 < |\bar{S}|=46$ , $\max(S)=100$

As the sets become rather large I left out the lasts few examples. These are the first sets I encountered in the following procedure.

We start for the chosen value of $l$ with the set $S=\{1,2,\dots,l-1\}$ which does not contain an arithmetic sequence of length $l$. (Optional $\bar{S}=\{l-1\}$). We also use an index $n=l$. Now we can use the following algorithm:

1. Add $n$ to the set $S$
2. Check wether there is any arithmetic sequence of length $l$ in $S$ that ends in $n$. If that is the case we remove $n$ from $S$, if not we have a new set that does not contain any arithmetic sequences of length $l$ or longer.
3. Optional: If $n$ was accepted we can check whether there is any arithmetic sequence of length $l-1$ in $S$ that ends in $n$. If that is so, we add $n$ to $\bar{S}$.
4. Increase $n$ by one and go back to step 1.

After that it is only repeating until the number of elements in $\bar{S}$ exceeds half the size of $S$.

I have not tried to prove the existence of such a set for any value of $l$, but I see no obvious reason why they would seize to exist for larger values of $l$. It should also be noted that there might very well be sets with the required properties that are smaller in size and of which the largest element in $S$ is less than the algorithm above gives.

It is, however, possible to construct a set for any value of $l$ in a systematic fashion. Hereto we start with the following sets:
$$S_0 = {1}$$
$$\bar{S}_0 = \emptyset$$
and apply the following iterative scheme:
$$S_{n+1} = \cup_{k=0}^{l-1} \left[ S_n + k \Delta_n \right]$$
$$S_{n+1} = \cup_{k=0}^{l-2} \left[ \bar{S}_n + k \Delta_n \right] \cup \left[S_n + (l-1) \Delta_n\right]$$
where $\Delta_n$ is not unique but should be large enough to avoid any problems with generating additional sequences. It is sufficient to choose $\Delta_n \geq 2 \max(S_{n-1})-1$.

We find that
$$|S_n| = l^n$$
$$|\bar{S}_n| = l^n - (l-1)^n$$
and if we choose
$$\Delta_n = (2l-1)^{n-1}$$
the largest element in $S_n$ is given by
$$\max(S_n) = \frac{(2 l-1)^n +1}{2}$$.

From this it follows that for $|S_n\setminus \bar{S}_n| < |\bar{S}_n|$ we require $(l-1)^n < l^n - (l-1)^n$, which means
$$n>- \frac{\ln 2}{\ln(1- \frac{1}{l})}$$.

For the case $l=3$ we would obtain the set 
$$S=\{1,2,3,~~6,7,8,~~11,12,13\}$$
and for $l=4$ we get
$$S=\left\{\begin{array}{llll}
1,2,3,4, & 8,9,10,11, & 15,16,17,18, & 22,23,24,25,\\
50,51,52,53, & 57,58,59,60,& 64,65,66,67, & 71,72,73,74,\\
99,100,101,102,&106,107,108,109,&113,114,115,116,& 120,121,122,123,\\
148,149,150,151,&155,156,157,158,&162,163,164,165,& 169,170,171,172
\end{array} \right\}$$.

And finally, we get that
$$\frac{|\bar{S}_n|}{|S_n|} = 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{l}\right)^n$$
and hence 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\bar{S}_n|}{|S_n|} = 1.$$